# What the permission required to view all the permissions on a given database?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, user-permissions

What permission can grant the right to view all the permissions on a given database?

In my current context, the support team of a piece of software need to be able to investigate the cause of permission problems, without being allowed to modify the permission themselves. I want them to be able to view the permissions of every login/user/roles of a database. If it's impossible on a database level, server level would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for documentation for the sys.database_permissions DMV:

> Any user can see their own permissions. To see permissions for other
>   users, requires VIEW DEFINITION, ALTER ANY USER, or any permission on
>   a user. To see user-defined roles, requires ALTER ANY ROLE, or
>   membership in the role (such as public).

And, according to the documentation for permissions on users, you can grant view definition on the user.

If you use anything remotely complex with your permissions though, I will say from experience that the ability to impersonate a user is *immensely* helpful in troubleshooting such things (as you can invoke things like `fn_my_permissions`, sys.login_token, and sys.user_token).

Comment: Impersonating a user is a powerful indeed, but in my context it's not possible. Being able to see the permission with the View Definition will actually be sufficient. J'll try that! Thanks :)

Comment: Sure. Only you know what's appropriate for your environment.

Answer (score 1):

This would be obtained by the [VIEW DEFINITION](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) permissions.

However you probably don't want to allow them access to your database servers.
An alternative way would be to query the permissions on your database, and supply them with the output.

This can be done using DMV's or SQL queries. There are some examples in [this StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)